# Apache can't be reached from outside local network

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi

Recently, my apache web server stopped working outside my local network. Devices that are on the same network can connect using either ipv4, public ip, or domain name (thus I don't believe it's a port forwarding problem), but outside the network, nothing connects to apache. I have also tried connecting to other hosted services using other ports, and it worked. My isp hasn't blocked port 80 and I think it's unlikely that they started blocking it.

Some changes I have made since testing outside connection:

- Configured my server to also run as a wireless access point using a bridge between `wlan0` and `eth0` interfaces (and now using `br0` ip address to connect to any service, including apache)
- Disabled ssl module for apache to renew certificates (which I couldn't do since certbot can't connect to apache for authorization)

One thing to note is that requests outside the local network don't seem to even reach Apache, as no error shows up in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: same!!! this started happening this weekend to me. Same exact thing. Apache on a raspberry pi. I played with this for 6 hours last night and got no where. I will defiinitely be following this thread to see if anyone can help both of us. I had even uninstalled apache and installed nginx to see if that was the issue. no luck. still wouldn't connect outside the network. so i put apache back on

Comment: have you found a solution for this problem?

Comment: no, I haven't unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the problem was with my router not forwarding port 80 on remote connections. I have no idea why that was, but after I deleted the port, added it again and rebooted the router it seemed to work.